# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum does not work in iOS 6 iPad 3

Tags: xcode, uiimage, ios6, photo, ipad-3

I'm using the next function to save photos in my app:

```
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pngImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), NULL);
```

It works well on iOS 5.1.1 devices, and iPod/iPhone iOS 6.0 devices.

But strangely photo saving doesn't work on iPad 3 with iOS 6.0 and returns the following error:

> Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3310 "Data unavailable" UserInfo=0x1cd6afc0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Launch the Photos application, NSUnderlyingError=0x1cdaa140 "Data unavailable", NSLocalizedDescription=Data unavailable}

Did anybody encounter this problem and what are the ways to deal with it?

Answer (score 13):

I was able to save to the Camera Roll but when I upgraded to iOS 6 it stops working.  It turns out my app needs (but does not have, this is new in iOS 6) permission to access the camera roll.  To obtain permission, go to Settings -> Privacy -> Photos.  I am able to save to the camera roll with 
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()
again.

Comment: I can't remember ever disabling this on the app I've been developing for the past two months. And all of a sudden it seems like the photos permission just disabled itself?? 

I will catch the error and ask permission again when to avoid this from happening

Answer (score 1):

The image is being written to the Camera Roll album. When used on an iOS device without a camera, this method adds the image to the Saved Photos album rather than to the Camera Roll album. ([UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum))

Looks like there are no Camera Roll or Saved Photos albums on your iPad and `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` can't find the matching album to save photo.

Launch Photos app as it mentioned in error recovery suggestion: `NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Launch the Photos application`
and then try to take photo via Camera app.