# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum not work in iPad with XCode 7.2

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm using this function to save image in Album :

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-29.png"], self,@selector(thisImage:hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:usingContextInfo:) , nil);
```

it's work other project but not work in my application and give me error :

> Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3310 "Data unavailable"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Launch the Photos application,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x14dcec40 {Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain
>   Code=-3310 "Data unavailable"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Launch the Photos application,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x1ab52eb0 {Error Domain=com.apple.photos Code=-3001
>   "(null)"}, NSLocalizedDescription=Data unavailable}},
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Data unavailable}

And also app in not in `Photos` section in `Setting` : 
 Settings -> Privacy -> Photos.

But not work in my application.

**EDIT :**

Getting Same error using `PHPhotoLibrary`

```
          [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
                PHAssetChangeRequest *changeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-29.png"]];
            } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                if (success) {

                }
                else {

                }
            }];
```

Error :

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2047 "Photos Access not allowed (authorization status 0)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Photos Access not allowed (authorization status 0)}
```

When i create new project than it working fine, but not in my app !
I also change bundle id to create new app in device, and also reset setting for permission.

Comment: I found this on another thread. This may help solving your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968486/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-does-not-work-in-ios-6-ipad-3

Answer (score 2):

As per the Apple document [ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)

> Assets Library framework is deprecated as of iOS 9.0

[image]

So, it is better to use [PHPhotoLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/PHPhotoLibrary) with more advance features.

Try this code:-

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization
{ (PHAuthorizationStatus status) -> Void in
     switch (status)
     {
        case .Authorized:
            // Permission Granted
            println("Write your code here")
        case .Denied:
            // Permission Denied
            println("User denied")
        default:
            println("Restricted")
        }
    }
```

Check this for Request Authorisation :- [authorizationStatus](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHPhotoLibrary/authorizationStatus)

Comment: getting same error using  PHPhotoLibrary. please see updated question,

Comment: Check it in three place . 1) #import <Photos/PHPhotoLibrary.h>
 2) in general -> Linked frameworks and libraries 3) Buildphases -> linkbinary with libraries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104847/discussion-between-badal-shah-and-bhadresh).

Answer (score 0):

```
Use This Method ... 


-(void) saveimage:(NSString *)imagename
{
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image,
                                   self,
                                   @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                   nil);

}
- (void) image:(UIImage*)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{




}
```

Comment: 'Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2047 "Photos Access not allowed (authorization status 0)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Photos Access not allowed (authorization status 0)}'

Comment: http://databasefaq.com/index.php/answer/341374/ios-iphone-swift-ios8-ios-swift-creating-app-folder-error